# Arrays not showing up inside structures

Tags: solidity, remix, arrays, struct

I am creating a record of people and have created a structure

```
struct asset{
    uint assetId;
    string hash;
    address creatorAddress;
    uint cost;
    uint soldCount;
}

struct person{
    uint personId;
    address personAddress;
    uint earning;
    uint tokenCount;
    uint[] assetsUploaded;
    uint[] assetsBought;
    bool initialized;
}

mapping (uint => asset) public assets;
mapping (uint => person) public persons;
```

I am creating a new person as

````
        persons[personCount].personAddress = _sender;
        persons[personCount].earning= 0;
        persons[personCount].tokenCount = 0 ;
        persons[personCount].initialized = true;
        persons[personCount].assetsUploaded = new uint[](0);
        persons[personCount].assetsBought = new uint[](0);```

after doing all this i am unable to know whether the array is created or not because it is not showing up in remix.

**REMIX OUTPUT**
0:
uint256: personId 0
1:
address: personAddress 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
2:
uint256: earning 0
3:
uint256: tokenCount 0
4:
bool: initialized false

assetsUploaded and assetsBought are missing here in the remix output

I am adding assets in assetsUploaded but am unable to see them. Is there any issue in the code which i need to fix?
````

Comment: What is `persons`?

Comment: mapping (uint => person) public persons;

Comment: Also, please share all the relevant details in **plain text** (no links or images).

Comment: "I am adding assets in assetsUploaded": What is `assets`??? How are you adding it???

Comment: This question is really low-quality!

Comment: I am extremely new to stack exchange. Please pardon me in case i am not able to convey it in a right manner.

Comment: I have made edits, if you could please help

Comment: For sure, `new uint[](0)` is a bad idea. You should use `push` in order to add new items.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117976/discussion-between-shrey-gupta-and-goodvibration).

Comment: Maybe Remix just doesn't show empty arrays? Try to create them not empty.